# BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner runner category not available

Tags: eclipse, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to Google dataflow, and I'm following the QuickStart guide from
[here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse) to build the sample wordcount project in Eclipse.

However, when I setup the "New Launch Configuration", there is no option "BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner" available as shown from the attached screen shot.  Only "DirectPipelineRunner" and "DataflowPipelineRunner" are available.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` and `DataflowPipelineRunner` have been merged. You should be able to use the `DataflowRunner`.

The blocking behavior is now available within code by calling [waitUntilFinish](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/PipelineResult.html#waitUntilFinish--) within the code, which the examples should do.